# Porting some C# code to F# with Action<T>

Tags: f#

I have the following C# code:

```
    _Client.Streams.InfoStream.Subscribe(async info =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"reconnection, message: {info.Info}, version: {info.Version:D}"));
        await _Client.Send(new PingRequest());
        ...
    }
```

and the following definitions are of interest:

```
    public IObservable<InfoResponse> InfoStream => InfoSubject.AsObservable();
    public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext)
```

when I want to call the  *_Client.Streams.InfoStream.Subscribe* method from F#, I do not know what the syntax should be:

```
   Client.Streams.InfoStream
        .Subscribe(
                      fun x -> ( printfn "%s" x.Info )
                  )
```

doesn't work. It tells me I'm returning an IDisposable type instead of a unit type. And this doesn't touch the async part yet.
what should the syntax be?

---

Edit:

Following the answer, here is the solution I came up with to run async code inside the callback:

```
       Client.Streams.InfoStream
            .Subscribe(
                fun _ ->
                    (
                        async {
                            [                                                    
                                Client.Send(new PingRequest()) |> Async.AwaitTask;
                                Client.Send(new BookSubscribeRequest()) |> Async.AwaitTask;
                                Client.Send(new TradesSubscribeRequest()) |> Async.AwaitTask;
                                Client.Send(new AuthenticationRequest(id, key)) |> Async.AwaitTask
                            ]
                            |> Async.Parallel
                            |> Async.Ignore
                            |> Async.Start
                            |> ignore
                        } |> ignore
                    )
            ) |> ignore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Subscribe` operation of an `IObservable` returns an `IDisposable` value that you can later use to cancel the subscription. In C#, you can just ignore return values, so C# implicitly treats this as an operation that returns `void`. In F#, you need to explicitly ignore results if you are not using them.

In your case, you probably need to write:

```
Client.Streams.InfoStream
    .Subscribe(fun x -> printfn "%s" x.Info)
|> ignore
```

**EDIT:** In your edited example, I think you just want to start all the individual tasks. For this, you don't need any F# async. Assuming the `Send` method creates a "hot task" (i.e. a task that has already started), the following should work just fine:

```
Client.Streams.InfoStream.Subscribe(fun _ ->
    Client.Send(new PingRequest()) |> ignore
    Client.Send(new BookSubscribeRequest()) |> ignore
    Client.Send(new TradesSubscribeRequest()) |> ignore
    Client.Send(new AuthenticationRequest(id, key)) |> ignore
 )
```

Comment: that's it! I never paid attention about what subscribe returned (and I'm still at the stage where I find f# error message a bit cryptic!). How can I do some async call in the function? since I need to call several methods returning tasks.

Comment: I edited the question with the async code I came up with; will that behave as expected?

Comment: @Thomas - See edit - I think you don't need F# async in this case.